# Change loaded images based on active tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, image

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhjkkds/1/

The ones currently loaded will be for "1". And I am trying to load 8 new ones each for 2, 3 and 4 (so 32 pics in total)

I was trying to follow this:

[jQuery - Change Image When Tab is Clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985911/jquery-change-image-when-tab-is-clicked)

But the URL is no longer working, which makes it difficult to see how the whole thing works together, and I require multiple images to change (not sure if this question requires just one) although like this one, I would like this functionality to be compatible with Wordpress.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  show: function(e,ui){
    switch(ui.panel){
      case $('#tabs-1')[0]: src = 'image1.jpg'; break;
      case $('#tabs-2')[0]: src = 'image2.jpg'; break;
      default: src = 'default.jpg';
    }
    $('#myimg').attr('src',src);
  }
});​​​​​
```

This code appears to change only one image based on the active tab, because each case contains only one src?

Comment: `case $('#tabs-1')[0]: $('#myimg1').attr('src','image1.jpg'; $('#myimg2').attr('src','image2.jpg';break;`

Comment: Thanks for this. Although, is it possible to see the entire thing working on my FIddle so I can understand better?

Comment: But your fiddle does not have any script to handle tabs.

Comment: Something like this maybe:

https://codepen.io/cssjockey/pen/jGzuK

Comment: Yes, then add your case after `var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab'); switch(tab_id){ ....`

Comment: The only thing is, in this implementation are all the images loaded at once? Because the images I am using are heavy so I only want the images to load when each tab is selected?

Comment: If you have placeholders for the images then you can load the heavy ones on click.

Comment: Yes these are just placeholders. So you are saying the cases enable each tab to load it's respective images on click?

Comment: Yes. The $('#myimg').attr('src',src); loads the image

Comment: I simplified my fiddle: 

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhjkkds/4/

I think I'm still a little confused though. Do I clear all the html out of each tab?

Comment: Use the cofepen code as basis

Comment: I have but doesn't this load everything in all tabs on page load?

Comment: Yes, hence you should have placeholders instead of actual images in the tabs

Comment: Like this?:

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhjkkds/6/

Comment: Something like that. Except I would remove `default: src = 'default.jpg';` and `$('#img').attr('src',src);` and perhaps have some src="blank.gif" in the html instead of no src

Comment: Like this now?:

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhjkkds/8/

It still doesn't work though?! Have you had an experiment with this fiddle yet?

Comment: your code is not correct. Please see console. All statements that change the src has a missing ) Also the code needs to run in head, not on load

Comment: Sorry I'm confused? JS Fiddle removes head tags? I have this now:

https://jsfiddle.net/jzhjkkds/9/

Comment: Click the (JAVASCRIPT) logo in the editor and change from "ONLOAD" to "IN HEAD"

Comment: Also you do not include the tabs code - look in the console to see the error - you need to tick jquery UI

Comment: I think you are mixing stuff. Bootstrap and Tabs. Please start over from a simple example from jquery UI

Comment: How do I "tick jquery UI"?

Comment: Check the jQUery in the (JAVASCRIPT*) button in the editor.